# Java generic usage question

Tags: java, generics

Say I want to do something like

```
public class Container<C extends Member> {

    public void foo() {
        C newC = new C();
    }
}
```

I realize that this will not work, but what is the correct Java idiom for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "this" is given your example. Could you describe the question differently?

Answer (score 2):

The generic type C is erased at runtime to java.lang.Object.  There is no way of instantiating an erased generic type.  It seems more like you want some sort of factory creational pattern?

```
abstract class MemberFactory {
   public static <T> Member create(Class<T> memberClass) throws Exception {
      return memberClass.newInstance();
   }
}

Member premiumMember = MemberFactory.create(PremiumMember.class);
```

If this is the case, you might want to look at using dependency injection and frameworks like Spring, or Guice.

Answer (score 1):

The typical idiom is indroducing a type tag passed in constructor:

```
public class Container<C extends Member> {
    private Class<C> tag;

    public Container(Class<C> tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void foo() {
        C newC = tag.newInstance();
    }
}
```